# Array Merge atráves de uma comparacao

Tags: php, array

Preciso comparar os arrays através da chave chamada codigo, e caso as chaves sejam iguais, juntar os arrays em um unico array, veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
 $array1 = array(array('id' => '1', 'codigo'=>'1155', 'preco' => '25.00'), 
                 array('id' => '2', 'codigo'=>'2280', 'preco' => '47.00')
                 );
 $array2 = array(array('id_produto' => '11', 'codigo'=>'2280', 'nome' => 'Produto Amostra P4', 'id_categoria' => '15'),
                 array('id_produto' => '12', 'codigo'=>'1155', 'nome' => 'Produto Amostra P7', 'id_categoria' => '19')
                );
```

O resultado esperado seria como o codigo abaixo:

```
$arrayResultado = array(array('id_produto' => '11', 'codigo'=>'2280', 'nome' => 'Produto Amostra P4', 'id_categoria' => '15', 'id' => '2', 'preco' => '47.00'), 
                        array('id_produto' => '12', 'codigo'=>'1155', 'nome' => 'Produto Amostra P7', 'id_categoria' => '19','id' => '1', 'preco' => '25.00')
                        );
```

Alguem poderia me auxiliar?

Comment: Veja:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14842272/php-array-merge-two-arrays-on-same-key

Comment: nao entendi o trecho array_map(function($a, $b), essas variaveis seriam os meus arrays? @Marconi

Comment: Marconi não deu certo entao, vou tentar  fazer algo parecido com a ideia que voce me passou como referencia

Comment: `array_map(function($a, $b)` com essas esses dois são os parametros de call back, aqui na própria documentação -> https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php voce pode encontrar vários exemplos e como o array_map funciona ao longo das versões do PHP.